# Client Primary DNS is set as Active Directroy Server IP

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, internal-dns

In my company, We have one Active Directory Server (Windows 2008 R2) and 13 Client Machines (Windows 7). This was configured by the old SysAdmin. The DHCP from Broadband Router sets Primary DNS of the Client Machines as the AD Server Address. 
Can anybody please tell me how clients connects to the internet through AD Server. Which settings in Server I can see these configuration.

Comment: Heads up - if you're having to ask this question, your company needs a new Active Directory expert. Serverfault is not intended to be a substitute for having a trained subject matter expert available to your company, and we are not going to be able to provide the training you need to properly support this environment. Please hire an expert or seek training immediately.

Comment: That's a good comment :) I like it. 
Meanwhile, I found out the answer, and corrected issues :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for clients to login to domain, their DNS IP must be Active Directory's IP. AD cannot work without DNS, when AD is installed DNS is also installed. If you see your client's Default Gateway would be the routers IP. This means that all the internet traffic goes to router. DNS is only there to resolve Domain Names. If I would configure this network, I would configure forwarding DNS on AD.
For more elaboration consider this scenario.

Network: 192.168.100.0/24
Router IP (Default Gateway): 192.168.100.1
AD IP: 192.168.100.10
DNS on Clients: 192.168.100.10

Please follow this link to see forwarder option in your scenario.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754941.aspx

Comment: ok. but, how I can access internet on client machines if DNS is set to AD IP ? AD should forward it to broadband router naa ? Where I can set router IP in AD ?